# REST API - Batch processing vs mutiple calls

Tags: python, r, api, batch-processing, flask-restful

I am writing the API to accept a `POST` request and provide the output. The use case is, I should be able to support single as well as inputs. So, I came up with a structure like this:

**Input:**

```
{
    "inputs": [{
            "id": 1,
            "foo": "bar"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "foo": "baz"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "outputs": [{
            "id": 1,
            "result": "bax"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "result": "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

This format supports both single as well as multiple calls. However, this means the API will have to handle CPU and Threads, e.g. an API call might contain 100 inputs and processing those might take a while. So, I need the inputs on the following points:

- If the API's responsibility is just to process an input then, should CPU/thread handling be done at consumer level and use multiple calls to process multiple inputs? (i.e. one input per call)
- If I switch to one input per call, I might end up making multiple calls (maybe with a different endpoint), will this be efficient (in terms of network traffic) against one call per let's say 100 inputs? (i.e. placing a hard limit per request)
- Is hybrid approach good idea? i.e. to process a batch of 1000 inputs, I can divide it in small batches of 100 inputs and make 10 calls
- The API will be written in Python/R and I do not have much exposure on how these languages handle multiple threads.

If this question suits more to Stack Exchange then I am happy for it to be moved across.

Comment: For second question, multiple calls mean multiple wastes of time on network. It will be slower.

Comment: I think batch processing is much better. But you need to build a structure to efficiently handle multiple tasks concurrently. For example, create a processes pool(Because of GIL, threads in Python won't use multiple cores.) and submit tasks to the pool, when all tasks finish, return the result.

Comment: @Sraw agreed, it's about the tradeoff between CPU time for multiple calls vs network latency for individual calls.

Comment: It seems that API design must be closer your task specification - if you initially have to process it in batches - make it a batch input. Network constraints are usually more binding than CPU use times.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak I want both the capabilities. Although the initial use case is batch, I want to be in a position where I can use the same API with minimal or no changes. Should I benchmark both the approaches?

Comment: I think there is no much conflict between the two approaches, at least on API level - you can send a bacth with a single entry. I'd just warn against two versions of API. If you need to separate processing of large or small loads - you can do it on server side, but outside call format better stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your web server to accept HTTP2 and write client calls with an HTTP2-aware library that can use HTTP2 multiplexing.

Top of google is https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

This allows you to revert to pure REST without batching, where the network impact of multiple calls is reduced by the HTTP2 connection multiplexing - i.e. just one connection between client and server is created.

It depends on the trade-off between maintainability and performance. HTTP2 will spare you the headache of managing multiple threads. Presumably though multiple calls will still have a network impact compared to batching, especially if the batches are large.